# Как разместить два последних элемента слева при justify-content: space-between

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Есть список карточек. Необходимо без левых/правых марджинов разместить два последних ребенка в флекс-контейнере слева контейнера при свойстве `justify-content: space-between;` [пример](http://joxi.ru/Q2KPoE6Cwjl1yA)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать без марджинов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак. Можно использовать `grid`.

```css
.cont {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  gap: 50px;
}

.cont div {
  border: 3px dashed red;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div>a</div>
  <div>SF</div>
  <div>sf</div>
  <div>sfse</div>
  <div>edf</div>
</div>
```

↑
**Разверните на всю страницу**

upd:
Все же можно использовать позиционионирование, но не думаю, что это хорошая практика

Comment: Спасибо!!  То что нужно