# Чем или как заменить justify-content: space-between?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, flexbox, выравнивание

Даже не заменить.. justify-content распределяет элементы неравномерно. Вот похожий вопрос - [Как разместить два последних элемента слева при justify-content: space-between](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1168810/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-justify-content-space-between). Сверстал сайт, потерял scss и теперь перевести в grid будет сложно. Какие есть варианты кроме маржинов? а если и они, то margin-left: -33% использовать? А если элементов будет не 8, как в примере, а 9, js? От костылей к костылям...

Изменено: Всё нормально,  scss найден:) Но всё же, как это делают другие сайты без гридов?

jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/pgh9j71a/17/

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.item {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос. То можно сделать невидимый элемент
https://jsfiddle.net/01b892qe/7/

Comment: чёртов гений! Правда без js не обойтись. Спасибо!

Comment: Кажется, делать такое гридами — единственный разумный вариант, а остальное даже если и работает, то костыли

Answer (score 0):

Блокам 33%, а в внутри блоков отступы.

Answer (score 0):

```
.container{ 
   text-align-last: justify;
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]